# System.ArgumentNullException in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm just a junior dev and I'm still studying the codebase in our company.
Here is the code that I created for unit testing the `hasProductImages` config, but I'm having a an error...

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

...in the last code , what could be the problem?

```cs
[TestClass]
public class ChooseProductViewModelTest
{
    ChooseProductViewModel chooseProduct;
    private EventAggregatorMock eventAggregator;
    private ProductRepositoryMock productRepository;
    private CategoryRepositoryMock categoryRepository;
    private PosDeviceSettingsMock posDeviceSettings;


    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        eventAggregator = new EventAggregatorMock();
        productRepository = new ProductRepositoryMock();
        categoryRepository = new CategoryRepositoryMock();
        posDeviceSettings = new PosDeviceSettingsMock();
        chooseProduct = new ChooseProductViewModel(productRepository, categoryRepository, eventAggregator, posDeviceSettings);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProductImageConfiguration_Verification_With_ProductItemViewModel()
    {
        chooseProduct = new ChooseProductViewModel(productRepository, categoryRepository, eventAggregator, posDeviceSettings);
        Assert.IsTrue((chooseProduct.Items.First() as ProductItemViewModel).hasProductImages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and start investigating why it returns null

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProductImageConfiguration_Verification_With_ProductItemViewModel()
{
    chooseProduct = new ChooseProductViewModel(productRepository, categoryRepository, eventAggregator, posDeviceSettings);
    var productItemViewModel = chooseProduct.Items.First() as ProductItemViewModel; //This line will obviously produce null
    Assert.IsNotNull(productItemViewModel);
    Assert.IsTrue(productItemViewModel.hasProductImages);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt fix my problem , maybe i need to investigate more why it returns null 

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: Of course, since you didn't provide code for ChooseProductViewModel all we can do is guess. Try to see if the first item in the Items Enumeration is in fact of type ProfuctItemViewModel, or rewrite to `choseProduct.Items.OfType<ProductItemViewModel>().First()`

Comment: Don't post a "Thank you" comment, please read [what to do when someone posts a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)